# Why does my Ubuntu 20.04(even 19.10) randomly shut down?

Tags: shutdown, 19.10, 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (used to run Ubuntu 19.10) on some an HP laptop[RAM-4 GB, Intel Core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz x 4, 1TB HDD, AMD Hainan/Intel HD Graphics 440 (HSW GT2)]. I have turned off all the automatic shut-down or suspend option, but it's still shutting down suddenly without even giving a warning. If I'm leaving the laptop unused for just a few minutes then this is happening, it also occurred while working as well! So. I'm a little worried about it.

I have really no clue why it's like this, so it would be really helpful if someone helps me, I tried to contact few servers regarding this but not get any answer honestly.

Is there somewhere I can do to fix this?

Comment: Could be overheating or faulty hardware. No way to tell without further investigation.

Comment: I'm ready to give the information, can you please ask me how to know it? Because I have used Windows on it and it works really fine. No issues at all, so I was expecting the Linux to be smooth too!

Comment: Also, when I'm video streaming with it or leaving it after joining any Discord channel it's not actually shutting down! So, I'm really confused that what is the case.

Comment: I assume you meant i3-4005U CPU not y3-4005U. Is there any relevant information in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`? Use turbostat  and run this command all the time, watch temperature: `sudo ./turbostat --Summary --interval 15 --show Avg_MHz,Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt`

Comment: [1/3] I checked the syslog and kern.log but didn't understand much. Today, there were two sudden shutdowns, on syslog I found 
`May  1 18:48:41 Linuxbook kernel: [ 6214.544377] perf: interrupt took too long (2611 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 76500
May  1 18:49:23 Linuxbook rtkit-daemon[1224]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.`
my system was shutdown exactly at 18:49
on kern.log, I found
`May  1 18:48:41 Linuxbook kernel: [ 6214.544377] perf: interrupt took too long (2611 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 76500`

Comment: [2/3] and the second sudden shutdown occurred 19:17, on syslog
`May  1 19:15:28 Linuxbook dbus-daemon[1829]: [session uid=1000 pid=1829] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'
May  1 19:15:28 Linuxbook gnome-logs[3761]: g_file_info_get_attribute_boolean: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_INFO (info)' failed
May  1 19:15:28 Linuxbook gnome-logs[3761]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
May  1 19:17:02 Linuxbook CRON[3779]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

Comment: [3/3] on kern.log
`May  1 19:14:29 Linuxbook kernel: [  543.816927] capability: warning: `gvfsd-admin' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)`

Comment: Since Windows seems to work fine on this machine, I'd probably rule out overheating. My next suspicion would be power states. It's possible Ubuntu is trying to use a power state that isn't playing well with your system. Try playing around with the power saving settings in the Bios?

Comment: 1. You may first find out whether it is a battery problem or not. As Ubuntu 20.04 does not show low battery notification, it could be the problem. To ensure that, you may use a simple Python script named [Battery Alert](https://github.com/duttaprasanta/battery_alert). This script can start as the laptop starts and maintains a log file indicating the discharging rate. It also sends you low battery notifications (also a sound notification) so that you never face the issue of the laptop shutting down due to low battery. 2. If it is not a battery problem, then it may be a hardware failure. In that

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution. The problem was related to graphics. After setting `nomodeset quiet splash` from `quiet splash` it started working fine.

[How to set 'nomodeset'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: This may not be the real culprit. Possibly you are just switching to a graphics driver that renders poorer and consumes less energy. Set your laptop to "power saver" profile may reach the same effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue within hours of installing 20.04, while the "nomodeset" did seem to temporarily solve the issue. The real problem turnout to be a power supply fault. With the new power supply, have changed grub back to "quiet slpash" random power offs have stopped. (I was also experiencing no display on wake from from suspend after applying the nomodeset fix, this was also resolve with the new power supply.)

Comment: By new power supply do you mean a new battery or a new charger or some new power hardware?